# Как мне правильно сделать, чтобы заработал поток?

Tags: c++, qt, qtcreator

Выдает ошибку.

```
QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.
(Parent is Updater(0x55d25094b5a0), parent's thread is QThread(0x55d24ff199b0), current thread is Updater(0x55d25094b5a0)
```

Создаю поток.

```
    updater = new Updater(0);
    updater->start();
```

вот хиадер

```
#ifndef UPDATER_H
#define UPDATER_H
#include <QtWidgets>
#include <QTcpSocket>
#include <QJsonObject>
#include <QJsonDocument>

class Updater : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Updater(QWidget *parent);
    bool isUpdated;
private:
    QTcpSocket *sock;
    void run();
public slots:
    void connected_to_server();
};

#endif // UPDATER_H
```

Вот класс.

```
#include "updater.h"
#include "version.h"


Updater::Updater(QWidget *parent) : QThread(parent)
{

}

void Updater::run()
{
    sock = new QTcpSocket(this);
    sock->connectToHost("192.168.1.2", 9336);


    connect(sock,SIGNAL(connected()), this, SLOT(connected_to_server()));

}

void Updater::connected_to_server()
{
    QJsonObject data;
    data["command"] = "update";
    data["os"] = "windows";
    data["version"] = PLAYER_VERSION;

    QJsonDocument doc(data);
    QByteArray byte_data = doc.toJson();

    qDebug() << byte_data;
    sock->write(byte_data,byte_data.length());

    char qdata[16386];
    sock->read(qdata, 16386);

    QJsonDocument jsonDoc = QJsonDocument::fromJson(qdata,nullptr);

    QJsonObject object = jsonDoc.object();

    if(object["done"].toBool() == true) {
        return;
    }

    QString file_path = object["file"].toString();
    unsigned long size = object["size"].toInt();

    QFile file(file_path);

    if(file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Truncate)) {

        while ( size > 0 ) {
            int ret = sock->read(qdata, 16385);
            file.write(qdata, ret);
            size -= ret;
        }
        file.close();
    }

    sock->close();
}
```

И вообще, правильно ли я делаю. правильно ли получаю данные от сервера? а то я в qt новичок.

Comment: почти наверняка отдельный поток тебе не нужен... нужно присоединиться к сигналу `readyRead()` сокета и читать по нему... ну и помни про вероятность произвольной сегментации в TCP...

Comment: Наследовать QThread не вполне правильное решение. Рекомендую ознакомиться https://habr.com/ru/post/150274/

Comment: @Fat-Zer ну мне же надо сначала отправить данные, потом получить ответ и если он тот который нужен, то принимать данные. с ready read не понятно как реализовывать. всякие так переменные нужно ставить чтоли, чтобы при приемы определяло, что приходит. поэтому я сделал так как есть. и мне бы таким способом показать как поток запустить, чтобы обновление загрузилось через отдельный поток.

Comment: @SergeyTatarincev почему так надо всё усложнять? это же обычный поток. не пойму этих программистов.

Comment: @xverizex, «так как есть» у тебя просто не будет работать — для корректной работы всё равно нужен будет цикл чтения со всеми вытекающими и оно получится ни чуть не проще... как именно сделать советовать не буду т.к. пока не понимаю, как у тебя в протоколе реализовано отделение json-заголовка от самого файла. Если ни как, то это плохой дизайн и корректно такую схему будет сделать относительно геморройно...

Comment: Собственно сейчас у тебя проблема, что ты `QTcpSocket`'у, который создаётся внутри потока пытаешься назначить родителем контроллер потока, который принадлежит основному потока... ну и кроме этого ты не запускаешь `eventLoop` в потоке (`QThread::exec()`), так что сокет внутри него работать не будет... но повторюсь, такое использование контрпродуктивно — потоки нужны для тяжёлых вычислений или обслуживания большого числа клиентов... в противном случае они создают больше проблем, чем пользы...

Comment: @Fat-Zer клиент отправляет json со своей версией. если на сервере нет версии выше этой, то отправляет json о том, что работа закончена, иначе отправляет json такой же почти, что работа есть и есть дополнительные поля с названием файла и его размером. после этого происходит передача файла. надо считать размер файла и как только ббудет равно нуля, то передача закончена. и всё.

Comment: @xverizex, это всё понятно... вопрос в том, чем отделяется json от последующего файла? концом строки? двойным переводом строки? если ни чем, то корректный и надёжный вариант определить это построить будет относительно сложно: нужно будет пробовать парсить буфер и по коду ошибки угадывать, где кончается заголовок...

Comment: @Fat-Zer а что, он не делаешь fflush(NULL); автоматически?

Comment: не знаю при чём тут `fflush()`... но чтение из tcp сокета представляет из себя сплошной поток байт, поделённый на произвольные сегменты... пересбор этого всего в сообщения — дело вышележащего протокола...